# How to change this property alert alert-error hide

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this:

```
<div class="row" style="display:none" id="divRegistration">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="@Model.EmailAddress" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" value="@Model.Password" required="" title="Please enter your password">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" value="@Model.ConfirmPassword" required="" title="Please confirm your password">
            </div>
            <div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Invalid registration</div>
            <a onclick="Register();" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="lead">Already Registered?</p>
        <p><a onclick="showLogInPage();" class="btn btn-info btn-block">LogIn</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I have tried all of these)

```
function Register() {
        $('#registerErrorMsg').html('hi andy!');
        $("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "none");
        $('#registerErrorMsg').fadeIn();
        $('#registerErrorMsg').show();
        alert('hi');
}
```

My alert box shows but my label does not?

Comment: I think the `$("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "none");` in your script make the alert div hidden, since you want to display the alert div then you should change this to something like `$("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "block");`... I've put the snippet on my answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My alert box shows but my label does not?

This happens because the class **hide** is defined in boostrap as:

```
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

So, it's enough to remove this class ([.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) or [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)).

Change from:

```
function Register() {
    $('#registerErrorMsg').html('hi andy!');
    $("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "none");
    $('#registerErrorMsg').fadeIn();
    $('#registerErrorMsg').show();
    alert('hi');
}
```

to:

```
function Register() {
     $('#registerErrorMsg').html('hi andy!');
     // $("#registerErrorMsg").removeClass('hide'); 
     //  ...or
     $("#registerErrorMsg").toggleClass('hide');
}
```

```js
function Register() {
    $('#registerErrorMsg').html('hi andy!');
    //$("#registerErrorMsg").removeClass('hide');
    $("#registerErrorMsg").toggleClass('hide');
}



$("#divRegistration").show();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row" style="display:none" id="divRegistration">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="@Model.EmailAddress" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" value="@Model.Password" required="" title="Please enter your password">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" value="@Model.ConfirmPassword" required="" title="Please confirm your password">
            </div>
            <div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Invalid registration</div>
            <a onclick="Register();" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="lead">Already Registered?</p>
        <p><a onclick="showLogInPage();" class="btn btn-info btn-block">LogIn</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See snippet below:
First you  need to change the:

```
<div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Invalid registration</div>
```

into this statement:

```
<div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error" style="display:none">Invalid registration</div>
```

Then change your script into:

```
function Register() {
        $('#registerErrorMsg').html('hi andy!');
        $("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "block");
        $('#registerErrorMsg').fadeIn();
        $('#registerErrorMsg').show();
        alert('hi');
}
```

The `$("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "block");` will change the `alert div` style from `none` to `block`, therefore your alert will be shown.

```js
function Register() {
        $('#registerErrorMsg').html('hi andy!');
        $("#registerErrorMsg").css("display", "block");
        $('#registerErrorMsg').fadeIn();
        $('#registerErrorMsg').show();
        alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row" id="divRegistration">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="@Model.EmailAddress" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" value="@Model.Password" required="" title="Please enter your password">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" value="@Model.ConfirmPassword" required="" title="Please confirm your password">
            </div>
            <div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-info" style="display:none">Invalid registration</div>
            <a onclick="Register();" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="lead">Already Registered?</p>
        <p><a onclick="showLogInPage();" class="btn btn-info btn-block">LogIn</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Sam.  I wanted to not put  style="display:none" in the markup if I could help you see but still a good answer